# What is a solution for putting dot in a variable in php?

Tags: php

I want to use this variable below with dot in php but server remove its dot, Is there any solution?

```
$file=adetails.php;
```

I can't change dot to another character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assigning a value to a variable and as I get it from your question `adetails.php` is a string value you would like to assign to `$file`. If that is the case, you need to enclose that string into quotes:

```
$file="adetails.php";
```

Comment: thanks ,it works ,i did't see your answer first,after 10 minutes i will accept you as well.

Comment: @Kaveh truth is Quentin beated me with a little bit, so probably he is the one that should have his answer accepted. And I will work on my typing speed ;)

Answer (score 3):

Quote your strings, don't rely on magic constants.

`$file=adetails.php;` means `$file = "adetails" . "php";`. The `.` is "lost" because it is a concatenation operator and not part of the string.

You want `$file = "adetails.php";`